# Standard XML Serialization but omit the parent tag

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have the following code that I attempt to serialize into XML format:

```
public class FieldServers
{
    public List<FieldServer> FieldServer = new List<FieldServer>();
}

public class FieldServer
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public List<Item> EntryPoints = new List<Item>();
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Data")]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Using the above class structure, I can generate some data like the one below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FieldServers>
  <FieldServer>
    <FieldServer ID="11">
      <EntryPoints>
         <Item Name="ItemName" Data="ItemData" Type="ItemType" />
      </EntryPoints>
    </FieldServer>
  </FieldServer>
</FieldServers>
```

Can anyone show me how I can modify the class serialization attribute to make the data look similar to the one below? I've been trying for the last hour without success.  Is this possible if I retain my List structures in the classes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FieldServers>
   <FieldServer ID="11">
       <Item Name="Item Name" Data="Item Data" Type="Item Type" />
       <Item Name="Item Name 2" Data="Item Data 2" Type="Item Type 2" />
   </FieldServer>
   <FieldServer ID="12">
       <Item Name="Item Name" Data="Item Data" Type="Item Type" />
   </FieldServer>
</FieldServers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you adorn your collection `FieldServer` and `EntryPoints` properties with the [`XmlElement` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) it will produce the XML you want:

```
public class FieldServers
{
    [XmlElement] //add this line
    public List<FieldServer> FieldServer = new List<FieldServer>();
}

public class FieldServer
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Item")] //add this line
    public List<Item> EntryPoints = new List<Item>();
}
```

EDIT: I missed the renaming of the `EntryPoints` element. Specify the element name in the attribute to have it match. (that is, have `[XmlElement("Item")]`)

Using your classes as you have them, I duplicated the same values and produced this XML with the attribute changes above:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FieldServers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FieldServer ID="11">
    <Item Name="Item Name" Data="Item Data" Type="Item Type" />
    <Item Name="Item Name 2" Data="Item Data 2" Type="Item Type 2" />
  </FieldServer>
  <FieldServer ID="12">
    <Item Name="Item Name" Data="Item Data" Type="Item Type" />
  </FieldServer>
</FieldServers>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it has to be simple, but thank you for a short to the point and elegant answer.